# How to show admin notices when checking WooCommerce version

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, versioning

I want to show an admin notice which should show if the WooCommerce is not at the latest version. I tried with the following function which does not work. Any help will be appreciated.

```
function check_wc_version($version = '2.6.1'){
    if ( function_exists( 'is_woocommerce_active' ) && is_woocommerce_active() ) {
        global $woocommerce;
        if( version_compare( $woocommerce, $version, ">=" ) ) {
            echo 'Show some notice here';
        } 
    }
}
add_action('admin_notices', 'check_wc_version');
```

Answer (score 1):

Well your function is on the right track, but doesn't work because the `$woocommerce` isn't a version number. It's a global variable that has been deprecated but holds the instance of the main `WooCommerce` class. You can now get the singleton instance of that class via the function `WC()`. And one of the class variables is `version` so you can get the current version of WC via `WC()->version`. Also, I think you need to flip your comparison operator around. Untested, but I think this would work.

```
function check_wc_version($version = '2.6.1'){
    if ( function_exists( 'WC' ) && ( version_compare( WC()->version, $version, "<" ) ) {
            echo 'You need a higher version of WooCommerce';
    }
}
add_action('admin_notices', 'check_wc_version');
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. Actually I ended up using a constant like this  if (defined('WOOCOMMERCE_VERSION') && version_compare(WOOCOMMERCE_VERSION, '2.6.0', '>=')) {